# UserManager.DeleteUser Specified method is not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

All I have installed the latest ASP.NET Identitiy following http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/20/test-announcing-rtm-of-asp-net-identity-2-0-0.aspx. Following the NuGet installation, I have intellisense access to the `DeleteUser`/`DeleteUserAsync` methods and the code compiles fine. However, at run-time when I invoke this method I get

> Specified method is not supported.
>
> Stack Trace: 
>   [NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.]
>      Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`1.DeleteAsync(TUser user) +59

The cause is clear, but how can I compile this and it now execute? What do I have to do to be able to delete a user using `UserManager`?

The current code I am using to do this is

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> RemoveUser(string userName)
{
    ApplicationUser user = null;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        if (user.IsAdmin != null && (bool)user.IsAdmin)
        {
            var userToRem = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.DeleteAsync(userToRem); <- EXCEPTION

            // If successful
            if (!result.Succeeded)
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable);
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tools");
}
```

I am not interested in anything fancy, all I want to do is remove a user and for some reason it is giving me a royal ball ache. Any other method would be appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `Insert`, `Update` and `Delete` operations to the context should be synchronous. `SaveChangesAsync` should handle the asynchronous commit to the database.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET Identity v1, DeleteAsync was not supported. Based on the error message you are seeing, it looks like you are referencing v1.

Try updating your ASP.NET Identity packages to v2.1.0 via Nuget.